# How Do I Calculate Average Clicking Speed in Java?

Tags: java, user-interface

I want to add a system that will calculate the average clicking speed of a person. So, is there a syntax that can be use to do this?

What I'm thinking of is that when the "Click" button is pressed, it should start some sort of timer and after about 15 clicks it should stop the timer. But if something else can be done thats fine too.

EDIT: Im getting confused as to how to limit it to 15 clicks. sorry im a beginner. Please tell that as well

I know i still haven't added anything to limit the clicks.. i'll add it later.

Here's the code:

```
private void createUI() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    label = new JLabel();
    speed = new JLabel();
    buttonClick = new JButton("Click");
    buttonGetResult = new JButton("Get My Average Click Speed!");
    buttonReset = new JButton("Reset");

    buttonClick.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            updateCounter();
        }});

    panel.add(buttonClick);
    panel.add(label);
    panel.add(speed);
    panel.add(buttonGetResult);
    panel.add(buttonReset);

    getContentPane().add(panel);
    setTitle("Click Speed Calculator");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    pack();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setResizable(false);
    setVisible(true);
}

public void updateCounter(){
    clicks++;
    label.setText("You have clicked " + clicks + " times");
    pack();
}
```

Comment: You could create a time that starts when the program runs, then anytime the user clicks, update a "clickCounter" variable. Then, to get average clicks per time running, just divide the number of clicks by the current elapsed running time of your program.  You could have it be average per millisecond/second/minute/etc.

Comment: So, what's the problem with your code?

Comment: there's no problem with the code. its just to show  what im trying to do. perhaps tell me where alterations could be made

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Limiting it to 15 clicks is just a simple if and else statement. just remove clicks++ from the updateCounter() method and put it over here

```
buttonClick.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(clicks <= 15){
            updateCounter();
       }else{
         //whatever you want to do   
        }
    }});
```